# I have a problem in my node.js project that I got 500 status code for requests that needs authorization even after I logged in and grant the token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-jwt

I have a problem in my node.js project that I got 500 status code for requests that need authorization even after I logged in and granted the token. For example, requests like posting products or categories should succeed, but they return a 500 status code.

I used the jsonwebtoken package, and here is the code for the login:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
     const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
     const secret = process.env.secret;
     if (!user) {
         return res.status(400).send('The user not found');
     }

      if (user and bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.passwordHash)) {
             const token = jwt.sign(
            {
                 userId: user.id,
                  isAdmin: user.isAdmin
            },
             secret,
             { expiresIn: '1d' }
         );
         res.status(200).send({ user: user.email, token: token });
      } else {
        res.status(400).send('Password is wrong!');
      }
  });
```

then I made this jwt.js

```
  const { expressjwt: expressJwt } = require("express-jwt");
  function authJwt() {
      const secret = process.env.secret;
      const api = process.env.API_URL;
      return expressJwt({
          secret,
          algorithms: ['HS256'],
          isRevoked: isRevoked
      }).unless({
          path: [
              {url: /\/public\/uploads(.*)/ , methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] },
              {url: /\/api\/v1\/products(.*)/ , methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] },
              {url: /\/api\/v1\/categories(.*)/ , methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] },
              {url: /\/api\/v1\/orders(.*)/,methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST']},
              `${api}/users/login`,
              `${api}/users/register`,
          ]
      });
  }

  async function isRevoked(req, payload, done) {
      if(!payload.isAdmin) {
          done(null, true)
      }

      done();
  }
  module.exports = authJwt;
```

Then the I used it in the app.js as middleware

```
const authJwt = require('./helpers/jwt');
app.use(authJwt());
```

I tried after logging to make requests that needs token to succeed but it return 500 status code and I can't find out the reason